# match value from one array with the key of another

Tags: php

PHP newb trying to find the value from `array2` in the key in `array1` and where they match do something to the value of `array1`. Pretty sure this is easy but am not massively familiar with php. Any help would be appreciated. Have been tinkering with array_search, in_array but unable to make anything work.

Hoped for result is where the value of `array2` is found in the key of `array1` the value of the matched key value pair would be divided by 2.

```
$array1 = Array ( 
     [shore_anchor] => 0 
     [inter_anchor] => 0 
     [offshore_anchor] => 0 
     [offshore_gear] => 5  
     [shore_infrastructure] => 0  
     [inter_infrastructure] => 0  
     [coastal_vessel] => 5  
     [offshore_vessel] => 5 );
$array2 = Array ( [0] => infrastructure [1] => anchor );

foreach($array2 as $key1 => $val1){
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
      if ($key1 == $key){
        echo "$key => $value <br />";
  }}}}
```

Comment: What result are you trying to get for these two arrays?

Comment: `$array1` keys are varchar, but `$array2` keys are numeric, so how do you expect them to match in `if ($key1 == $key)`?

Comment: basically to divide the value of `array1` by 2 if say infrastructure is found in they key of `array1`

Comment: have been trying array_flip just now

Comment: @hselbie add your expected result into your question.

Comment: the reason why i'm only echoing the result is once i've isolated the appropriate matches I can just assign a new value with `$newval= $value/2;` i'm assuming. My problem is isolating the matches.

Comment: the keys in array1 are not identical to the values in array2, you will have to split the underscore to do a proper match\

Comment: @Dagon, is there no way to match a substring in a key?

Comment: there are several. -- post the expect output and i'll write an example, as it stands im not sure what you expect to see from your echo

Comment: expected output would be [shore_anchor] => 0 
     [inter_anchor] => 0 
     [offshore_anchor] => 0 
     [shore_infrastructure] => 0  
     [inter_infrastructure] => 0

Comment: @hselbie please, add the expected outcome to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be it, but comments or efficiencies are welcome.

```
$result = array_flip($array2);

foreach($result as $needle => $val1){
    foreach ($array1 as $haystack => $val2) {
        if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            echo "$haystack => $val2\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way:

```
<?php
$array1 = Array(
        'shore_anchor'=>0,
        'inter_anchor'=>0,
        'offshore_anchor'=>0,
        'offshore_gear'=>5,
        'shore_infrastructure'=>0,
        'inter_infrastructure'=>0,
        'coastal_vessel'=>5,
        'offshore_vessel'=>5
);

$array2 = Array(
        '0'=>'infrastructure',
        '1'=>'anchor'
);


foreach ($array1 as $key=>$value){
    $x = explode('_',$key);

    if (in_array($x[0],$array2) || in_array($x[1],$array2)){
        echo "$key => $value <br />";
    }
}

// for PHP 5.6.0 +



$match = '#' . implode('|',$array2) . '#';


$x = array_filter($array1,function ($key) use ($match){
    return preg_match($match,$key);
},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);


foreach ($x as $key=>$value){

    echo "$key => $value <br />";
}
```